# rtabmap: g2o, GTSAM

Tags: slam, navigation, opencv, ros-kinetic, g2o

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. why do I need them?
2. I have installed rtabmap-ros as ROS package. Have I already running g2o and GTSAM?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343139/rtabmap:-g2o,-gtsam/) by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2020-02-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. From this [paper](https://introlab.3it.usherbrooke.ca/mediawiki-introlab/images/7/7a/Labbe18JFR_preprint.pdf) (section 3.5):

> When a loop closure or a proximity
> detection are detected or some nodes
> are retrieved or transferred because
> of memory management, a graph
> optimization approach is applied to
> minimize errors in the map.  RTAB-Map
> integrates three graph optimization
> approaches:  TORO [Grisetti et al.,
> 2010], g2o [Kummerle et al.,2011] and
> GTSAM [Dellaert, 2012].  g2o and GTSAM
> converge faster than TORO, but are
> less robust to multi-session mapping
> when multiple independent graphes have
> to be merged together.  TORO is also
> less sensitive to poorly estimated
> odometry covariance.  However, for
> single map, based on empirical data,
> g2o and GTSAM optimization quality is
> better than TORO, particularly for
> 6DoF maps.  GTSAM is slightly more
> robust to multi-session than g2o, and
> thus is the strategy now used by
> default in RTAB-Map contrarily to our
> previous works using TORO.

2. g2o may be already used if you installed rtabmap-ros from binaries (apt-get). To verify if g2o and GTSAM are supported in your current build, do:

   $ rtabmap --version

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2020-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0